# Why is my UILabel not initializing when using another language? (iOS localization)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, uilabel

I'm applying localization to an iPhone app I'm working on, and slowly going through all texts/strings/labels throughout the app to dynamically retrive the correct language translation done through Localizable.strings - I'm testing with two languages to make sure it's working properly. Naturally English, and also Czech.

So far I haven't had any problems until this one particular UILabel.

While using the iPhone and app in English, no problems at all. However when changing the iPhone language to Czech and testing the app, one of my UILabels won't even initialize. It doesn't even matter if I force the text like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"show: %@", self.segmentedControlTitle);

    self.segmentedControlTitle.text = @"test";

    // Other code
}
```

Basically, when in the other language, it just displays the place holder text set in the Storyboard. All other titles that I have set so far work perfectly even using the actual localization method;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // The other code...

    [self.segmentedControl setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"VIEWALL_all", nil)
                 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
}
```

Any ideas? Can post more code if wanted, but I'm assuming everything is correctly established seeing as though it all works in English. It has to be something simple I've overlooked. I've tried Clean, deleting the app from simulators and my iPhone, trying the build again... same story. Happens on colleague's iPhone as well.

Thanks in advance. (Also I'm still a bit new to iOS dev just FYI)

Dave

Comment: Could you please explain `wont even initialize`? You mean to say this particular `UILabel` wont appear ?

Comment: Sure, sorry should have specified. I cannot set its text property as it is null. I attempt to NSLog() the label to see if I even get an object, and all I get it "null" - so I'm assuming it isn't initializing. When in English, NSLog() shows the whole object in the output

Comment: Are your storyboards localized?

Comment: I'm assuming so. I have two instances of the Storyboard:
MainStoryboard.storyboard (English)
MainStoryboard.storyboard (Czech)

Comment: Ok so I can set a static value for the label in each language within the Storyboard itself. But doesn't that somewhat defeat the purpose of having a the strings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Carl Veazey. Your comment helped me figure this out.

So I've learnt the lesson that when you apply localization, you can actually apply it to your storyboard as well - hence creating separate ones for each language.

So my problem was that the English version of the storyboard has the IBOutlet connection, whereas the Czech one did not.

Because I'll be applying all strings like this programatically from the Localizable.strings files, I don't need the storyboard to be localized - I have since removed the Czech version and am applying everything by code. I figure this is better practice anyway.

Thanks again!